# get indices of keys in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a fast way to get indices of a value from data.table? I have set a column as key, however, I struggle to find efficient way to get its indices?

```
x <- sample(letters, 200, replace = TRUE)
y <- rnorm(200)
DT <- data.table(x, y, key = "x")
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Execution time:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:1000) DT[.("g"), which= TRUE]) # 0.3 sec
system.time(for(i in 1:1000) which(DT$x == "g")) # 0.004 sec
system.time(for(i in 1:1000) which(df$x == "g")) # 0.004 sec
```

I guess currently it is not able to use key for finding index in the last two execution. Is there any fast way?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be 1) running into the time it takes to use `[.data.table` and 2) likely running into a lot of overhead to start the join operation only for only 200 rows. Going up to 2,000,000 rows results in the `DT[.("g"), which = TRUE]` to be very fast.

```r
library(data.table)
x <- sample(letters, 200, replace = TRUE)
y <- rnorm(200)
DT <- data.table(x, y, key = "x")
bench::mark(which(DT$x == "g"),
            DT[.("g"), which = TRUE])

## # A tibble: 2 x 13
##   expression                   min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>               <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 which(DT$x == "g")         7.9us  11.2us    88385.    1.66KB
## 2 DT[.("g"), which = TRUE] 735.8us 905.8us     1010.   64.73KB

## 20,000 rows:

## # A tibble: 2 x 13
##   expression                 min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>               <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 which(DT$x == "g")       251us  265us     3654.   159.5KB
## 2 DT[.("g"), which = TRUE] 744us  907us      879.    67.8KB

## 2,000,000 rows:

## # A tibble: 2 x 13
##   expression                   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>               <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 which(DT$x == "g")       21900us 24.9ms      40.6    15.6MB
## 2 DT[.("g"), which = TRUE]   868us  1.1ms     724.    366.1KB
```

Comment: This makes sense, however, we are not able to exploit binary search feature of data.table for smaller sets (20k rows are pretty common). It would be good to have something that could deliver results faster as keys are already saved.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta sounds like good feature request